# Efficient method for minimizing $f = x^4 + 2y^4 + 3z^4$ over the unit sphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, substitution

I'm helping a student prepare for a final, and they've been provided with a set of sample problems, with approximate points that the problem would be worth. A typical long-answer, show-all-your-work problem is worth 10pts. Answer-only problems are 5pts.

The following question is given as an answer-only, 5pt question:

> Minimize $f = x^4 + 2y^4 + 3z^4$ over the unit sphere.

But I cannot find an approach to solving it that seems on par with the difficulty of the problem, implied by its context.

I tried the following methods:

1. I started in on this using the method of Lagrange multipliers, but the number of sub-cases is unwieldy, and would clearly take more time (not to mention writing space) than makes sense, given the context.
2. I then briefly considered using Lagrange in spherical coordinates, but it is quickly apparent that this too is not a more effective method.
3. I also considered taking the constraint and subbing into the original function, *e.g.* $x^2 = 1 - (y^2+z^2)$, which yields $$f = 1- 2(y^2 + z^2) + 2y^2z^2 + 3y^4 + 4z^4 $$
   The critical point analysis is manageable, especially if one starts with this method (but I don't see how one would know this *a priori*).
4. Finally, I tried taking a substitution $u = x^2$, $v = y^2$ and $w = z^2$, this gives the system $$\begin{cases}f =  u^2 + 2v^2 + 3w^2 \\[5pt] u + v + w = 1 \end{cases}$$ which is extremely simple to solve, using Lagrange multipliers, and it gives the correct value for the minimum; however, **I feel deeply uncomfortable with this substitution: I simply don't know under what conditions such a substitution is justified...**

I feel like I'm circumambulating some theory that would simplify this entire question, but I can't put my finger on it.

I apologize that this isn't a more pointed question -- but I think it's a case of "Knowing the question is knowing the answer."

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: You could use [Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality) with the vectors $(x^2,\sqrt{2}y^2,z^2)$ and $(1,1/\sqrt{2},1)$. You get that $1=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\leq (1^2+(\sqrt{2})^2+1^2)(x^4+2y^4+z^4)$. This gives you a lower bound, which is attained when the two vectors above are proportional.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I've never heard of the C-S inequality being used in this context, but look forward to diving down that rabbit hold, as well :D However, I'm certain that the course only covers basic methods of an introductory multivariate course at the undergrad level...

Comment: Well, then know that this is a pretty common technique, and know more, the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) and any other that gives a bound with conditions when the equality occurs are also pretty common. They solve many of these didactic exercises without having to compute much.

Comment: Now I see that there is a $3$ in front of the $z^4$. And I also forgot some reciprocals. That means that the inequality is a little different. It should be $1=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\leq(1^2+(1/\sqrt{2})^2+(1/\sqrt{3})^2)(x^4+2y^4+3z^4)$. This is Cauchy-Schwarz applied to the vectors $(1,1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{3})$ and $(x^2,\sqrt{2}y^2,\sqrt{3}z^2)$. As before, the inequality gives a lower bound, which is attained when the two vectors are colinear.

Answer (score 1):

The direct approach of $(4x^3,8y^3,12z^3)=\lambda(2x,2y,2z)$ seems straightforward.

However your method 4 is a very good one.It is often a good idea with Lagrange multipliers to choose the variables carefully.

Comment: It's straightforward, but the number of subcases one has to analyse are (unreasonably) numerous (i.e. given the context). Do you know when / if / how to know whether the choice of variables will affect our solution? I've never seen this done, I just tried it and saw that it worked...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by subcases. Are you referring to $x=0$ etc?

Comment: Pardon me, yes, that is what I meant: systematically working through each possibility for $x =0$, then for $y = 0$, then for $x^2 = 4y^2$ (and this is only the beginning)...

Comment: Re your general question about other occasions when a change of variable might work. The most common that I have seen do involve squaring eg if you are maximising the square root of something then don't! Maximise its square.

Comment: So, as long as none of $x,y,z$ is $0$, we have $x^2=2y^2=3z^2$ (along with the original sphere equation). You're right that you do get extra critical points at the 6 points on the axes and a few more when $x=0$ *or* $y=0$ *or $z=0$. When you make the substitution, you get faked out because the change of variables is not valid locally when you hit the axes.

Comment: There is the issue of $x,y,z$ being zero but otherwise you have $\lambda=2x^2=4y^2=6z^2$ which is straightforward.

Comment: @S.Dolan: But squaring the function to be optimized is a different justification from introducing squares in the independent variables. The folding onto the plane $u+v+w=1$ introduces hidden critical points at the axes.

Comment: @TedShifrin - I'm so in the habit of avoiding division when solving these (to avoid division by zero), that I ignored the simplification that it provides, in this context. However, how can one see that the change of variables i not valid "locally" (indeed, what does that mean)? I can post as a separate question - but I feel like this is probably what I've been trying to get at... Would it just be in terms of the derivatives, e.g. checking to see if the Jacobian is nonzero?

Comment: @RaxAdaam: So let's think of this carefully in terms of composition of functions. I'm only going to do the non-constrained case here. Let $\phi(x,y,z) = (x^2,y^2,z^2)=(u,v,w)$ and write $g(u,v,w) = u^2+2v^2+3w^2$. Then $f=g\circ\phi$. The chain rule tells you that $Df(x,y,z) = Dg(x^2,y^2,z^2)D\phi(x,y,z)$. So even if $Dg$ is never zero, if $D\phi(\vec V)=0$ then, $Df(\vec V) = 0$. This is the phenomenon I was referring to with folding onto the constraint plane.

Comment: In terms of practical advice to your student I think it is important to stress that the direct approach is fine if you use common sense as well. For example, in view of the symmetry of the domain the cases of variables being zero reduces immediately to $z=0$ or $y=z=0$ - there is no point in looking at the other cases which are obviously worse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a response to the following question from the OP.

*Do you know when / if / how to know whether the choice of variables will affect our solution? I've never seen this done, I just tried it and saw that it worked...*

Consider your change of variable and ask yourself a simple question.

Are the values attained by $x^4 + 2y^4 + 3z^4$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 $ precisely the same as the values of $u^2 + 2v^2 + 3w^2$ subject to $u+v+w = 1, u,v,w\ge 0 $?

If $x^4 + 2y^4 + 3z^4=A$ for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 $ then for $u=x^2$ etc we have $u^2 + 2v^2 + 3w^2=A$ with $u+v+w = 1$. The converse is just as easy.

So the values are the same and therefore the minimum values of the two problems are the same, **irrespective of any special features of the change of variable**. There is therefore no reason to think further about such a change of variable and especially not if you are in an exam where you are expected to give a multiple choice answer!

Also it should be noted that there are **no** special concerns here about critical values. Since we have seen that the two problems are fully equivalent then there could only be genuine concern about the modified problem if there was something wrong in general with the method of applying Lagrange multipliers.

For your problem you need to look at critical values just as you would for any Lagrange multiplier problem. In the case of your modified problem the values of $1$ for any variable means that the other variables are zero so you can just deal with those cases. Since interchanging the values of $u,v,w$ does not affect the constraint then we clearly only need consider either $w=0$ or $v=w=0$ and there is little difficulty in dealing with these two cases (or quickly dismissing them in a multiple choice exam).

Comment: Thank you for this. My only issue is formalizing the intuition you rely upon in this answer: i.e. that the values of the two problems are the same, specifically with respect to the domains (which *are* different, no)? Perhaps I'm over-thinking it, but I guess I wouldn't be totally confident generalizing this approach: is there some way of determining when "special features of the change of variable" will be relevant, and when they won't? Apologies if this is elementary, I suspect I need to investigate change-of-variables in more depth, along the lines suggested by Ted Shifrin...

Comment: I don't think the formalising is that tricky. I'll add in a note above and then you can see if there's anything that's still 'intuitive'.

Comment: In terms of generalising, I think simply checking "does the function still take the same values" is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $f$ is minimum when the two surfaces

$$\begin{cases}f =  x^4 + 2y^4 + 3z^4 \\[5pt] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \end{cases}$$

are tangential to each other. So, match their normal vectors,

$$(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z},1) = (\frac{x^3}{3z^3},\frac{2y^3}{3z^3},1)
\implies x^2 = 2y^2 = 3z^2$$

for the constraint on the points. Then, plug it into the plane equation to get the tangential points

$$(x^2,y^2,z^2)=(\frac6{11},\frac3{11},\frac2{11})\tag 1$$

Thus, the mimimum $f$ is

$$f_m = \left(\frac6{11}\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac3{11}\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac2{11}\right)^2=\frac6{11}$$

Note that there are multiple points given by (1) that admit the same minimum value.

Comment: You're missing *lots* of constrained critical points. How do you know that none of those will be relevant?

Comment: You might misunderstood. I pointed out there are multiple points which are all accounted for by presenting them with $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$.

Comment: Once again you're saying things that make no sense to me. See my comments below the next answer.

Comment: I noticed that you commented on constraints for optimization, which is not the solution presented here

Comment: The issue is that you may have divided by $0$. Of course, the method of Lagrange multipliers matches normal vectors (up to scalar multiple), too.

Comment: That’s fair, but could be avoided. The ratios used for the vector components are for comparison convenience and may be scaled to avoid the division

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \overbrace{x^4 + 2 y^4 + 3 z^4}^{=: f}\\ \text{subject to} & x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\end{array}$$

Introducing Lagrange multiplier $\mu$, we eventually obtain the following system of four polynomial equations in unknowns $x$, $y$, $z$ and $\mu$

$$\begin{aligned} x \left( 2 x^2 - \mu \right) &= 0\\ y \left( 4 y^2 - \mu \right) &= 0\\ z \left(6 z^2 - \mu \right) &= 0\\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &= 1\end{aligned}$$

and, hence,

$$\begin{aligned} x = 0 \lor x^2 = \frac{\mu}{2}\\ y = 0 \lor y^2 = \frac{\mu}{4}\\ z = 0 \lor z^2 = \frac{\mu}{6}\\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\end{aligned}$$

Let us introduce $\color{blue}{\beta_x, \beta_y, \beta_z \in \{0,1\}}$ and write

$$x^2 = \beta_x \frac{\mu}{2}, \qquad y^2 = \beta_y \frac{\mu}{4}, \qquad z^2 = \beta_z \frac{\mu}{6}$$

Obviously, $\beta_x = \beta_y = \beta_z = 0$ is not admissible, as the origin is not on the unit sphere. Hence, we are left with $2^3 - 1 = 7$ cases. From the equality constraint, we obtain

$$\mu = \frac{12}{6 \beta_x + 3 \beta_y + 2 \beta_z}$$

and, evaluating the objective function $f$,

$$f = \left(\frac{6 \beta_x + 3 \beta_y + 2 \beta_z}{24}\right) \mu^2 = \frac{6}{6 \beta_x + 3 \beta_y + 2 \beta_z}$$

and, thus, the minimum is attained when $\color{blue}{\beta_x = \beta_y = \beta_z = 1}$. The minimum is $f_{\min} = \frac{6}{11}$.